# Do not show redirected directory in the URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How to redirect the website from `htdocs` to a subdirectory `/htdocs/web` and not show `/web` in the URL?

Current working solution in the `htdocs/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/$1 [L]
```

It works for homepage only - it does not show `web`, but when visiting any subpages e.g. `About` page, the url shows as `example.com/web/about`, but it should be `example.com/about`.

Note this is a dynamic CMS PHP website with database, there are no static pages. Also very limited shared-hosting, no way to edit any Apache configs, etc., only what's inside htdocs.

**update2**

This approach initially removes `/web/` when visiting subpages from homepage, but adds it back in the URL when e.g. revisiting same page or other subpages from same menu within the subpage.

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [L,NC]`

Visiting from homepage
[image]

Visiting from subpages
[image]

Comment: That rewriting rule is _not_ responsible for what you describe. It does not redirect at all, it is an _internal rewrite_ which does _not_ alter the URL requested by the browser which is visible in the address bar. So most likely it is your CMS logic that realizes that it is requested inside the "web" folder and creates links that already contain that folder name. That is nothing you can change by rewriting, but only inside the CMS logic. Most such solutions support some setting like a "base path" or similar. Check the documentation.

Comment: The CMS is Drupal 10 and it does not create any links. The links are created by user with absolute paths, /web/ is nowhere in the database.

Comment: The user may _enter_ references into the CMS, but ultimately it is the CMS that creates links as part of the html it outputs to the requesting client. Take a look into the html source of a "page" you requested from your CMS. What do the `href` properties of anchors show as path? I _bet_ they already contain the "web/" ...

Comment: I see where you're going, but this is not the issue.

Comment: So your html does _not_ contain links with a leading "web/" in them? After you implemented that rule? Then I do not see where that should come from in the browser's address bar. Once more: that rule you implemented does _not_ do a redirection at all. There has to be some other factor involved here.